# Using coffees or teas to discuss a combination of multiple varieties

Tags: singular-vs-plural

In the following statement **"This company prepares a blend of coffee."**, should we use coffees in place of coffee since blend means a mixture of different things? So here it should mean a mixture of different varieties of coffee.

Similarly in such a statement if tea replaces coffee, then should we use teas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree.  It should be either "a blend of *coffees*" or "a *coffee blend*"

> This brand of tea is actually a blend of several popular **teas**.
>
> This brand of tea is actually a **tea blend**.

You can use this for many things, not just tea or coffee:

> *Garam masala* is actually a **blend of spices**, not a single spice
>
> *Garam masala* is literally a **spice blend**, since *masala* means "mixed".